# Caching a rendered (heavy) view in AngularDart to prevent regenerating a complex DOM

Tags: dart, angular-dart

#### Background

I am building an application which will poll the server for large data sets, and in turn process the response using the D3.js visualisation library. The user will then have the ability to further manipulate the view by - for example - overlaying other related data sets.

This area of the site will reside under `/app/dataview`, and the requirement is that each view should have an unique URL for sharing/bookmarking. I am thinking that using queryParameters would be the most convenient way to implement this as it would not require using a DB/datastore to map a URL to a corresponding configuration

```
/app/dataview?q=<<_queryStr_>>
```

where <<_queryString_>> would be (urlencoded)

```
{
    "title": "ABC",
    "layers": [
        {
            "q": "SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE name='AAPL' ..."
        },
        {
            "q": "SELECT * FROM tblA WHERE name='MSFT' ..."
        }
    ]
}
```

Given that each data set

- will require a server request/response;
- can be up to 10MB in size; and
- can take up to 15 secs to process and render using D3.js (previous acid test using a non-AngularDart approach)

and taking a 2-layered example, the data sets supporting the page could be ~20MB in size and take ~30 secs to completely render in the DOM.

(Note that the target audience will have access to fast, reliable internet connections and the application is targeted at modern browsers.)

I would like AngularDart/the browser to cache this view in some way so as when navigating between views A and B, returning to view A would not simply trigger a new 30 secs delay for the user.

I've considered using LocalStorage although the main issues are that my content will most likely exceed the 5MB limit; and that saving the resulting HTML fragments as strings would be a slow process, not to mention the fact that they would incur a large overhead when re-inserting.

I've also considered using IndexedDB although my main concern is again when attaching/detaching document fragments to the DOM, events can be troublesome to manage. Also, I'm not overly concerned with saving state outside of the user session so I'd like to try managing content within AngularDart if at all possible. When the user closes the browser, I'm happy for the views to be garbage collected.

#### Question

Is caching a partial DOM/document fragment possible using an AngularDart Service eg. `@Injectable() class CustomService { ... }` or is there another feature in AngularDart that I'm unaware of? I've found [ViewFactoryCache](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular-core.ViewFactoryCache) in the documentation but don't understand if this is designed for this purpose.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: AFAIK `ViewFactoryCache` is for compiling (parsing expressions and generate Dart code from it) and cache the result (can be done at build time using a transformer from what I remember). What about just hiding/showing the view instead of removing/adding. Fastest but might cause other problems (for example DOM gets too big)

Comment: Thanks for the info @Gunter, I'll take a further look at `ViewFactoryCache` and the transformer option you mentioned. As for the hide/show suggestion, although valid, there is a high possibility that there may be up to 10 views displayed this way and given the large data and complex DOM, the page would most likely crawl/crash so I'd like to avoid this scenario if at all possible.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of the disadvantages, but I assumed that inserting into the DOM is a more expensive part. Besides that  you probably have only the options you mentioned yourself alredy.